# How to retrieve specific characters within rows of database column?

Tags: oracle

Which Oracle SQL query is preferred or ideal to return the second, third and fourth positioned characters within rows of a particular column? A SQL statement using the `SUBSTR` method or some type of REGEX?

The following is the query I am trying to use:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(city) 
FROM student.zip;
```

I would appreciate any recommendations-thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question's not brilliantly clear, but if you want the 2nd, 3rd and 4th characters in the column `city`, in the table `zip`, then use `SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(city,2,3) 
FROM student.zip;
```

`REGEXP_INSTR` returns the location of a match, not a string, so you don't want to use that. `REGEXP_MATCH` would be the one to use, but `SUBSTR` is simpler.